# elasticsearch doesn't find results when searching the exact term

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using the [elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) module in my nodejs app to query my index using fuzzy completion. The text I'm trying to search is `Rome–Fiumicino Leonardo da Vinci International Airport`. when searching this term I get no results, but if I cut the term to 50 characters it does find it and return results.

```
const result = await elasticsearch.search({


     index: 'myIndex',
      body: {
      suggest: {
       fuzzinessZero: {
        text,
        completion: {
          field: 'name_suggest',
          fuzzy: {
            fuzziness: 0,
          },
          contexts,
        },
      },
      fuzzinessOne: {
        text,
        completion: {
          field: 'name_suggest',
          fuzzy: {
            fuzziness: 1,
          },
          contexts,
        },
      },
      fuzzinessTwo: {
        text,
        completion: {
          field: 'name_suggest',
          fuzzy: {
            fuzziness: 2,
          },
          contexts,
        },
      },
    },
}
    })
```

This is the result I get in `fuzzinessOne`
[image]
As you can see, the result in the `text` field is cut to 50 characters (maybe that's the issue). And inside the `_source` I get back all the inputs which is used for the search, and one of them is the full exact term which I tried to search, as well with all the other available combinations available.

It is worth mentioning that I'm using AWS openSearch.
And this is the settings which I use to create the index:

```
    settings: {
  analysis: {
    filter: {
      autocomplete_filter: {
        type: 'edge_ngram',
        min_gram: 2,
        max_gram: 20,
      },
      shingle_filter: {
        type: 'shingle',
        max_shingle_size: 3,
      },
    },
    analyzer: {
      autocomplete: {
        type: 'custom',
        tokenizer: 'standard',
        filter: ['lowercase', 'shingle_filter', 'asciifolding'],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Same problem [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/completion-suggester-issue/316657)

Comment: So this is a known bug?

Comment: I believe yes. I don't know if there is an issue open in git.

Comment: It looks weird to me, I mean the issue in the link is reported in the official elastic discuss, if the bug was specific in the npm package it would make sense, but in elasticsearch this supposed to be a big issue, a bug that should've been resolved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because of default value of `max_input_length` parameter is set to `50`.

Below is description given for this parameter in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester):

> Limits the length of a single input, defaults to 50 UTF-16 code
> points. This limit is only used at index time to reduce the total
> number of characters per input string in order to prevent massive
> inputs from bloating the underlying datastructure. Most use cases
> won’t be influenced by the default value since prefix completions
> seldom grow beyond prefixes longer than a handful of characters.

You can use this default behaviour or you can updated your index mapping with increase value of `max_input_length` parameter and reindex your data.

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "namesuggest": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase_analyzer",
        "preserve_separators": true,
        "preserve_position_increments": true,
        "max_input_length": 100,
        "contexts": [
          {
            "name": "searchable",
            "type": "CATEGORY"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "ignore_malformed": "true"
      },
      "refresh_interval": "5s",
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "number_of_shards": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it must be some config issue, just couldn't find this param...